# can't use httmock with slash (/)

Tags: python

My httmock attempt does not work with a slash.

```
from httmock import urlmatch, HTTMock
import requests


@urlmatch(netloc=r'(.*\.)?test.com/hi')
def google_mock(url, request):
    return 'Feeling lucky, punk?'

with HTTMock(google_mock):
    r = requests.get('http://test.com/hi/')
    print(r.text)
```

Does not work but

```
from httmock import urlmatch, HTTMock
import requests


@urlmatch(netloc=r'(.*\.)?test.com')
def google_mock(url, request):
    return 'Feeling lucky, punk?'

with HTTMock(google_mock):
    r = requests.get('http://test.com/')
    print(r.text)
```

Does work.

I debugged it and only difference is / in the url.
Do you hve any idea?

Comment: The netloc is the combination of host name and port. It does not include the path. See [urlparse docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlparse).

Comment: @KlausD. Thanks! Can you post this as an answer so I can add this as solution?